# POST string data with HttpUrlConnection as binary/octet in Android/Java

Tags: java, android

After some hours research, I haven't found any solution that contains my problem.

I have a `String` value that I want to send it via `POST`.

I've build something. I just don't know how to set that it will be send as binary/octet-stream.

```
String data = someData();
String sUrl = "http://some.example.website.com";
URL url = new URL(sUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(sUrl)).openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
```

I'm using `HttpUrlConnection` because I used `DefaultHttpClient()` that is deprecated.

I hope someone can help me!

Kind Regards!

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?. Also you can use the DefaultHttpClient(), eve though it is deprecated. If you want I can share the DefaultHttpClient() code that I use in my app.

Comment: Yes share it please. I thought i replace DefaultHttpClient() with HttpUrlConnection. As i see I cannot do, what I want. Please share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like the below snippet:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

String responseXml = null;
StringEntity se = "test string to be sent to the server";


HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(temp);
try {
    se.setContentType("text/soap+xml");
    httppost.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
    responseXml = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
    Log.d("Response XML", responseXml);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
}
```

I used this code to send a xml to the server. You can replace what you want to send in the se variable.